# What is going on the background of Decision Trees?

Tags: regression, cart

I'm trying to figure out what's going on in Decision Tree's background. I understand the Decision Tree's on classification problem but I don't understand the Regression problem on Decision Tree's.

What is going on the background in Regression problem with using Decision Tree?

For example, in the simple data,

> (x1,x2,x3 labels,y output)

```
3.2,4.7,5.3,13.2
2.1,3.9,6.7,12.7
2.4,3.8,5.5,11.7
2.7,3.9,5.8,12.4
```

How can I draw the decision tree?How can I determine the rule of each nodes of the tree and what is the leaf nodes values?

Comment: The difference is that you want to predict the value of y given x1, x2 and x3. In classification use x1, x2 and x3 to assign y to one of 2 or more classes. The branches of the tree for both regression and classification is constructing splits based on the value of the variable e.g.  x2<10 vs x2>= 10 or x1 belongs to the interval [1, 7] versus x1 is outside that interval.  The terminal nodes are values of y for regression whereas they are a particular category in classification.

Comment: Yes, I know this but I'm wondering that how can it found the rules of nodes. For example in the regression problem there are infinite real numbers, but how it chose a rule for nodes? For example if a nodes rule is x1<7.4, where does 7.4 come from?